# How can I open multiple worksheets, add the sum of the columns in each of them and save it?

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to program a macro in excel for my thesis. I got multiple .xlsx Files in a folder, each containing a table of 9 columns (A-I) and a varying number of rows. I would like to automatically open each file, add the sum of the columns on the bottom of each column and afterwards save the file.

I have found a code here in stack overflow to choose a folder with .csv files which are automatically opened and saved as .xlsx files in the same folder. I tried to modify the code for my purpose. 
The only thing I achieved was to change the code so far as to open the .xlsx files of my folder. 
From that point on I have no idea how to go on since I don't have any experience with VBA. 
GetFolder() is a definded function which allows me to browse for a folder and get out it's path.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim myFolder As String
Dim getBook As String
Dim myCSVFile As String
Dim LastRow As Long


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
myFolder = GetFolder()
myXLSXFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.xlsx")

Do While myXLSXFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFolder & "\" & myXLSXFile
    getBook = ActiveSheet.Name
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"
```

I think at this point the code for adding the sum at the end of the column should be but im not sure

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myFolder & Chr(92) & getBook, FileFormat:=51
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    myXLSXFile = Dir
Loop
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO :

To sum you column you might use something like this

```
SumA = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(columns("A:A"))
```

And to put it at the end of each column you will :

**1 Find the last row of the column**

```
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

**2 Store the sum value into the las cells column**

```
Cells(lastrow,"A").value = SumA
```

The last thing you got to do is to put a loop to do it for all columns and to browse all file :

**EditedCode**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, i     As Integer, j As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
directory = "C:\Users\ba-sc\Desktop\Fiji output\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
Do While fileName <> ""

Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

Set sht = Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastColumn = Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To LastColumn

SumA = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(i))
MsgBox SumA
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow + 1, i).Value = SumA

Next

'now save and close this workbook

Workbooks(fileName).Close SaveChanges:=True

fileName = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199039/discussion-on-answer-by-dorian-how-can-i-open-multiple-worksheets-add-the-sum-o).